# jQuery to check if checkbox is checked on button click, then do multiple AJAX requests to PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, checkbox

**Hi, I was wondering if it was possible to write some jQuery to check if on a button click, check if a certain checkbox is checked, and carry out an AJAX request to a PHP file.**

The response if successful should post the JSON values to the *"results"* and *"results2"* div on my main html page.

I have tried the following code below

```
<form action="PHP.php" id="test" method="post">

<input type="checkbox" name="check1" value="1"/>one<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="check2" value="2"/>two<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="check3" value="3"/>three<br />

<input type="submit" id="submit_button" name="sub" value="Show"/>

</form>
        <script>

        $('#submit_button').click(function(){   
        event.preventDefault();         
            if ($('.check1').is(':checked')) {

            $.ajax({
                url: 'PHP.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: json,
                success: function(data){

                    $("#results").empty();
                    $("#results").append(data); 


                    console.log(data);
                }

            });

            }

            if ($('.check2').is(':checked')) {

            $.ajax({
                url: 'PHP2.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: json,
                success: function(data){

                    $("#results2").empty();
                    $("#results2").append(data); 


                    console.log(data);
                }

            });

            }

        });

        </script>

</div>

<div id="results">
</div>

<div id="results2">
</div>
```

Note: the PHP.php and PHP2.php file which I am loading I am only echoing JSON at the moment, until I can get this working, but the console is not logging any data at all.

**I am having a bit of trouble in getting this to work. I was hoping for some help, or some guidance on the best way to do this?**

**Thanks in advance.**

Comment: change  `data: json` to `dataType: 'json'`

Comment: Change name of `checkboxes` it should be same and apply `class` to each checkbox else you can't get it `$('.check1').is(':checked')`

Comment: Ah, @NarendraSisodia, that worked, I hadn't made use of `class` , Thank you!

Comment: Actually...that always returns the ajax success, even if the checkbox is not checked.

Comment: change your function(){ to function(event){ in first line after <script>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking something like this:

**Form:**

```
   <form action="PHP.php" id="test" method="post">
        <input type="checkbox" name="check1" value="1" />one
        <br />
        <input type="checkbox" name="check2" value="2" />two
        <br />
        <input type="checkbox" name="check3" value="3" />three
        <br />
        <input type="submit" id="submit_button" name="sub" value="Show" />
      </form>
```

**Script:**

```
  <script>
    (function($){
      $('#test').on('submit', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var $checkbox = $(this).find('input[type=checkbox]');
        $checkbox.each(function(e){
          if($(this).is(':checked') ){
            var $name = $(this).attr("name");
            switch($name){
              case "check1": 
                // Do some AJAX operation
                break;
             case "check2": 
                // Do some AJAX operation
                break;
             case "check3": 
            // Do some AJAX operation
             break;
            }
          }
        });
        return false;
      });

    }(jQuery));
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in HTML, add class in each checkbox

```
<input type="checkbox" class="check1" name="check1" value="1"/>one<br />
<input type="checkbox" class="check2" name="check2" value="2"/>two<br />
<input type="checkbox" class="check3" name="check3" value="3"/>three<br />
```

and in ajax part enclose json by single quote:

```
dataType:'json'
```

Answer (score 0):

try it

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="PHP.php" id="test" method="post">

<input type="checkbox" id="check1" value="1"/>one<br />
<input type="checkbox" id="check2" value="2"/>two<br />
<input type="checkbox" id="check3" value="3"/>three<br />

<input type="button" id="submit_button" name="sub" value="Show"/>

</form>
        <script>

        $('#submit_button').click(function(){   
        //event.preventDefault(e);         
            if ($('#check1').is(':checked')) {

            $.ajax({
                url: 'PHP.php',
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(data){

                    $("#results").empty();
                    $("#results").append(data); 


                    console.log(data);
                }

            });

            }

            else if ($('#check2').is(':checked')) {

            $.ajax({
                url: 'PHP2.php',
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(data){

                    $("#results2").empty();
                    $("#results2").append(data); 


                    console.log(data);
                }

            });

            }

        });

        </script>

</div>

<div id="results">
</div>

<div id="results2">
</div>
```